Help Needed: ADNS-9500 Optical Sensor Movement Detection with ESP32 Wroom
I'm currently working on a project with an ADNS-9500 optical mouse sensor and an ESP32 controller board. The aim of the project is to move the optical sensor and have the ESP32 recognise the movement. I am able to detect the sensor connected to the ESP32, however, I'm not able to measure or track any movement.
I am extremely new to programming, i.e. I have no experience and I'm mainly using ChatGPT for assistance. I am able to upload files to Arduino IDE successfully. If anybody out there could offer me any assistance at all, I would greatly appreciate it.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Downloaded and used various files from GitHub
Successfully connected the sensor and uploaded the firmware
Verified the sensor is detected by the ESP32
Followed multiple setup and initialisation steps

However, despite these efforts, I haven't been able to get the ESP32 to track the movement of the sensor. If anyone has experience with the ADNS-9500 sensor and ESP32 or could provide guidance on troubleshooting steps or correct implementation, I would be very grateful.
#include <SPI.h>

// Registers
#define REG_Product_ID 0x00
#define REG_Revision_ID 0x01
#define REG_Motion 0x02
#define REG_Delta_X_L 0x03
#define REG_Delta_X_H 0x04
#define REG_Delta_Y_L 0x05
#define REG_Delta_Y_H 0x06
#define REG_SQUAL 0x07
#define REG_Pixel_Sum 0x08
#define REG_Maximum_Pixel 0x09
#define REG_Minimum_Pixel 0x0a
#define REG_Shutter_Lower 0x0b
#define REG_Shutter_Upper 0x0c
#define REG_Frame_Period_Lower 0x0d
#define REG_Frame_Period_Upper 0x0e
#define REG_Configuration_I 0x0f
#define REG_Configuration_II 0x10
#define REG_Frame_Capture 0x12
#define REG_SROM_Enable 0x13
#define REG_Run_Downshift 0x14
#define REG_Rest1_Rate 0x15
#define REG_Rest1_Downshift 0x16
#define REG_Rest2_Rate 0x17
#define REG_Rest2_Downshift 0x18
#define REG_Rest3_Rate 0x19
#define REG_Frame_Period_Max_Bound_Lower 0x1a
#define REG_Frame_Period_Max_Bound_Upper 0x1b
#define REG_Frame_Period_Min_Bound_Lower 0x1c
#define REG_Frame_Period_Min_Bound_Upper 0x1d
#define REG_Shutter_Max_Bound_Lower 0x1e
#define REG_Shutter_Max_Bound_Upper 0x1f
#define REG_LASER_CTRL0 0x20
#define REG_Observation 0x24
#define REG_Data_Out_Lower 0x25
#define REG_Data_Out_Upper 0x26
#define REG_SROM_ID 0x2a
#define REG_Lift_Detection_Thr 0x2e
#define REG_Configuration_V 0x2f
#define REG_Configuration_IV 0x39
#define REG_Power_Up_Reset 0x3a
#define REG_Shutdown 0x3b
#define REG_Inverse_Product_ID 0x3f
#define REG_Motion_Burst 0x50
#define REG_SROM_Load_Burst 0x62
#define REG_Pixel_Burst 0x64

#define ncs 5  // Adjust as per your wiring
#define MotionPin 15  // Adjust as per your wiring

volatile long Ticks = 0;
volatile byte motionBurstData[14];

// Firmware data (example data, replace with actual data)
const unsigned short firmware_length = 4096;
const unsigned char firmware_data[] = {
  // Actual firmware data should be here
  0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, // Example
  0xFF
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(ncs, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotionPin, INPUT);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setFrequency(1000000);  // Set SPI frequency for reliability
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);

  performStartup();
  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Wait a moment!");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    Serial.print("*");
    delay(50);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Pull the strip now!!!!!!");
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  performMotionBurstRead();
}

void adns_com_begin() {
  digitalWrite(ncs, LOW);
}

void adns_com_end() {
  digitalWrite(ncs, HIGH);
}

byte adns_read_reg(byte reg_addr) {
  adns_com_begin();
  SPI.transfer(reg_addr & 0x7f);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  byte data = SPI.transfer(0);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  adns_com_end();
  delayMicroseconds(19);
  return data;
}

void adns_write_reg(byte reg_addr, byte data) {
  adns_com_begin();
  SPI.transfer(reg_addr | 0x80);
  SPI.transfer(data);
  delayMicroseconds(20);
  adns_com_end();
  delayMicroseconds(100);
}

void adns_upload_firmware() {
  Serial.println("Uploading firmware...");
  adns_write_reg(REG_Configuration_IV, 0x02);
  adns_write_reg(REG_SROM_Enable, 0x1d);
  delay(10);
  adns_write_reg(REG_SROM_Enable, 0x18);
  adns_com_begin();
  SPI.transfer(REG_SROM_Load_Burst | 0x80);
  delayMicroseconds(15);

  for (int i = 0; i < firmware_length; i++) {
    unsigned char c = firmware_data[i];
    SPI.transfer(c);
    delayMicroseconds(15);
  }
  adns_com_end();
  Serial.println("Firmware upload complete.");
}

void performStartup(void) {
  Serial.println("Starting ADNS-9500 Initialization...");
  adns_com_end();
  adns_com_begin();
  adns_com_end();
  adns_write_reg(REG_Power_Up_Reset, 0x5a);
  delay(50);

  byte motion = adns_read_reg(REG_Motion);
  Serial.print("Motion: 0x");
  Serial.println(motion, HEX);

  byte dxl = adns_read_reg(REG_Delta_X_L);
  byte dxh = adns_read_reg(REG_Delta_X_H);
  byte dyl = adns_read_reg(REG_Delta_Y_L);
  byte dyh = adns_read_reg(REG_Delta_Y_H);
  Serial.print("Delta X: ");
  Serial.print(dxh, HEX);
  Serial.print(dxl, HEX);
  Serial.print(" Delta Y: ");
  Serial.print(dyh, HEX);
  Serial.println(dyl, HEX);

  adns_upload_firmware();
  delay(10);

  byte laser_ctrl0 = adns_read_reg(REG_LASER_CTRL0);
  adns_write_reg(REG_LASER_CTRL0, laser_ctrl0 & 0xf0);
  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Sensor initialization complete.");
}

void performMotionBurstRead() {
  Serial.println("Reading motion burst...");
  adns_com_begin();
  SPI.transfer(REG_Motion_Burst);
  delayMicroseconds(1);

  for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    motionBurstData[i] = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  }

  adns_com_end();
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  adns_write_reg(REG_Motion, 0x00);

  Serial.print("Motion Burst Data: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    Serial.print(motionBurstData[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();

  if ((motionBurstData[0] & 0x80) >> 7 == 1) {
    Ticks++;
    Serial.print("Ticks: ");
    Serial.println(Ticks);
    ShowMotionBurstData((byte*)motionBurstData);  // Cast to non-volatile pointer
  } else {
    Serial.println("No motion detected.");
  }
}

void ShowMotionBurstData(byte* motionBurstData) {
  Serial.print("Motion: 0x");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[0], HEX);

  Serial.print("Observation: 0x");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[1], HEX);

  Serial.print("Delta_X_L: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[2], DEC);

  Serial.print("Delta_X_H: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[3], DEC);

  Serial.print("Delta_Y_L: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[4], DEC);

  Serial.print("Delta_Y_H: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[5], DEC);

  Serial.print("SQUAL: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[6], DEC);

  Serial.print("Pixel_Sum: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[7], DEC);

  Serial.print("Maximum_Pixel: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[8], DEC);

  Serial.print("Minimum_Pixel: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[9], DEC);

  Serial.print("Shutter_Upper: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[10], DEC);

  Serial.print("Shutter_Lower: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[11], DEC);

  Serial.print("Frame_Period_Upper: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[12], DEC);

  Serial.print("Frame_Period_Lower: ");
  Serial.println(motionBurstData[13], DEC);
}




You need to give us some details about your circuit (ie. schematic) and your code for us to offer some help/guidance.

Apologies, I have no idea what I'm doing here. I have edited my original post with the information you requested. Thanks.

This is  helpful but you are still missing some information.  The schematic you provided is only of the motion sensor.  You need to provide a schematic showing how it is wired to the ESP32 and anything else that might be connected (ie. a power supply or anything else).
The code doesn’t seem to do any verification that it is actually talking to anything.  It just spits out what it is doing and would likely give the same output if you disconnected the sensor entirely.  You probably don’t have your wiring hooked up properly.

"Verified the sensor is detected by the ESP32", how did you do that? so far there is nothing in your code indicate that. 1) ESP32 has more than one SPI, which SPI interface you connected to? 2) According to the datasheet, if you read data from Product_ID register, it will return 0x33, you should used this to verify if your SPI work correctly before proceed for further communicating with the sensor.
